# XmlSerializer: How can I allow a property to deserialize, but then stop it from serializing?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

That is, I'd like my data to go one way - feed into a class, but then prevent it from saving out during a serialize operation.  What's the best way to go about that?

Comment: FYI, the XML Serializer is not related to C#. It's part of .NET.

Comment: @John: Good point. Changed tags appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried the `return null;` suggestion, but it doesn't work; it fails to deserialize.  However, here's a workaround:

```
public List<Program> Programs
{
    get
    {
        System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTrace.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            if ("XmlSerializationWriterApplication".Equals(stackTrace.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name))
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return programs;
    }
    set { programs = value; }
}
```

While probably not very performant, this examines the StackTrace to see who called the `get` - and if it's the Serializer/Writer, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to serialize a property that does `Set` correctly but always returns a fixed, fake value on `Get`.  For example, if the property were called `Password`, you'd create a `SerializablePassword` property that fits the above design, while not serializing the original.

*edit*

Here's Ani's sample, formatted, with one change:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public string Password { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Password")]
public string SerializablePassword
{
  get { return null; }
  set { Password = value; }
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, I considered that.  However, if I did something like get { return null; }, then I couldn't access the value internally.

Comment: @end-user: Setting `SerializablePassword` would set the same backing field as `Password`, so getting `Password` would work just fine.

Comment: +1 @ Steven: Something like this, if I understand correctly? Good idea, bit of a hack though.. :)

[XmlIgnore]
public string Password {get; set;}

public string SerializablePassword 
{
get {return null;}
set {Password = value; }
}

Comment: @Ani: Yes, that's right. I just stole your sample, adding an attribute to control the name of the XML element. But, yes, it's admittedly something of a hack. If `SerializablePassword` could be made `protected`, that would be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the full control over the serialization process you can implement the interface [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Also implement the special constructor.

EDIT:
I meant [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx). Thanks John.